# Handle categorical class labels for scikit-learn MLPClassifier

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, scikit-learn, multi-class

I have a handwritten dataset for classification purpose where the classes are from `a-z`. If I want to use [MLPClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/skl%E2%80%A6), I think I cannot use such categorical classes directly because MLP implementation in scikit-learn only handles numerical classes. Thus, what is the appropriate action to do here? How about converting these classes to be numbered from 1-28, does it make sense? If not, does scikit-learn provide special encoding mechanism for class labels to handle this case (I guess one-hot encoding is not the option here)?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [MLPClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html) you can do exactly what you suggested, that is represent classes as integers from 0 to 27 (in the case of 28 classes). [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neural_networks/plot_mnist_filters.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-neural-networks-plot-mnist-filters-py) is an example with MLPClassifier and MNIST dataset.
You can use sklearn to transform data to such format with [Label Encoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html).

Although the above will solve your problem, I believe MLPClassifier actually transforms the numerical labels to one-hot vectors for the neural network. Using lower level neural network libraries you would have to do it yourself. 
 This is because in multi-class classification the last layer's activation is softmax, which outputs a vector of n (number of classes) elements with continuous (0, 1) values. This makes sense as an indication of probability of observing a given class. To transform numerical labels to one-hot vectors with sklearn you can use [Label Binarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html). When we expect a neural network to predict a numerical value we're really talking about a regression, not classification.